# IE and hover state freeze

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, dom

while working on a project we come up on a bug which presents only in IE browsers. Here is JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tuHew/1/

Steps to reproduce:
1) Click on the middle div with text inside
2) Move your mouse out of result view
3) See frozen hover state only in IE

It works just fine in all the other browsers but it seems that in IE when element is removed from DOM it holds current element state in memory and when it's reinserted it already misses "hover out" event and any style which is associated with ":hover" pseudo class is frozen until you hover over with your mouse.

Does anyone know if it's IE bug or IE "feature"?

edited: try to see difference in IE and Chrome/Firefox !don't forget to move your mouse away immediately after clicking inside div!

Comment: Works fine on IE10, although it's not particularly clear what you're trying to show.

Comment: Seems fine in IE9 also - all DIVs return to green when I mouseout, clicked or otherwise.

Comment: I managed to reproduce this 'feature')) @others, simply move the cursor away from the red blocks after clicking and the block will reappear _red_, but it's clone - _green_. I'd say you can't actually control it, it's just the way IE does it imo

Comment: skip405 understood it right - after clicking - move your cursor immediately away